# The type 'XElement' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

A nonsensical error, because compiling another project works

System.Xml.Linq is referenced, it's the same code from this other project

csproj is similar, only with different compilation files(I'm comparing with the other project)

This other project is referenced, With .dll
I'm actually making a mod for a game(The game is offline and without ads as it is paid, Probably no problem)

I'm using mono, Using msbuild and not xbuild

this is the code:

```
XElement node2 = ContentManager.Get<XElement>("Widgets/SavedWorldItem");
var containerWidget = (ContainerWidget)Widget.LoadWidget(this, node2, null);
```

Line one is no problem, line two is the problem

This is the csproj: https://pastebin.com/sY5WJSUT

I just installed mono via apt-get, which should get the latest version

I don't understand why this error occurs

I found that any function that has an argument of type XElement causes this error, I will try to reinstall mono

Comment: I'm not sure, but probably it's a `Mono` issue. Try to update to the latest version.

Comment: The mono used is the latest

Comment: Post the .csproj contents. And state which version(s) of .net / mono you are using.

Comment: Done, csproj added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to solve my problem.

I got the APK of the game I'm making the mod for; I extracted all libraries; I referenced all with the help of scripts; then I removed the ones that are in conflict. And success!

It simply compiled normally and it worked.